# Select a dataframe from a list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

With this function:

```
def df_printer(*args):
    print(#DATAFRAME NAMED BALANCES#)
```

and 3 dataframes passed to the function:

```
df_printer(users, orders, balances)
```

Is there any way to reference these dataframes other than it's position? Can I reference them by name somehow? In this case, the balances df.

Comment: Would putting them in a dictionary work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `**kwargs` you can have a variable amount of keyword arguments accessible as a dictionary:

```
def df_printer(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs["balances"])


df_printer(users=users, orders=orders, balances=balances)
```